# no suitable constructor found for BufferedWriter(String)

Tags: java, constructor, bufferedreader

I'm having trouble with using a buffered readers. I've learned that they aren't given a string, they're typically given another reader, so here I was instructed to use InputStreamReader. I keep getting this "no suitable constructor found for BufferedWriter(String)" error on 2 of my BR's, one for input and another for output.

This is how all my BR's are constructed:

```
BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inFile));
```

and here is some other info on the errors:

```
BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inFile));
                                             ^
constructor InputStreamReader.InputStreamReader(InputStream,CharsetDecoder) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor InputStreamReader.InputStreamReader(InputStream,Charset) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor InputStreamReader.InputStreamReader(InputStream,String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor InputStreamReader.InputStreamReader(InputStream) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to InputStream by method invocation conversion)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Judging from what I see, `inFile` must be a `String`.

Comment: if your _content_ is in a String, then use a StringReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to input a String to your BufferedReader, you can pass a java.io.StringReader instance to the constructor:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("some string"));
```

Comment: That worked for the input but not the output buffered reader. How would you do it for the counterpart?  BufferedWriter outStream = new StringReader(outFile);

Comment: The opposite direction is to use a StringBuilderWriter from apache commons io (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4 if you're using maven) : BufferdWriter outStream = new BufferdWriter(stringBuilderWriter);  where stringBuilderWriter = new StringBuilderWriter(). If you want the actual string just call stringBuilderWriter.toString()